# How to change color density in scatter plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have an optimizer getting 2-d initial points and produces an answer which is 2-d. The following is the plot where red dots are initial points and blue dots are solutions.

[image]

I cannot see the density of the solution points as I go further in my loop as follows.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
exp = 100
for i in range(exp):
  fx = convex()
  #plotting initial points
  plt.scatter(fx.x[0],fx.x[1], c='r',s=1)

  #Finding optimal solution 
  while fx.fvalue() > 1e-4:
    fx.new_x(l2=True, alpha = 6, sgd = True)
  #plotting optimal solution
  plt.scatter(fx.x[0],fx.x[1], c='b', s=1)
  plt.xlabel('x')
  plt.ylabel('y')
  plt.legend(['Initial values', 'Solutions'])
```

`fx` is an instance of `convex` class which has `x` as its attribute and initialized randomly, then it gets updated in the while loop.

I want see the accumulation of the solution points dynamically or at least after ending `for` loop.

Comment: make the blue points semi-transparent, e.g. `alpha=0.3`?

Comment: @Stef it does not help because for the following figures you would get the same color.
```python
for i in range(50):
  plt.scatter(0,0, s=10, alpha = 0.3)

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(300):
  plt.scatter(0,0, s=10, alpha = 0.3)
```

Comment: Hmm, you mean because 50 or 300 markers with alpha=0.3 on the same spot both result in a fully opaque point? In this case of large numbers of semi-transparent markers at the same position this won't work. I have no other idea than, maybe some kind of 3D where you see the accumulation in the z axis (though I'm not sure if I correctly understand what your final goal is).